# Topological space $X$ which the set of non-constant real-valued continuous function on $X$ is empty

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-empty and topological space. The set of all real-valued continuous function and all non-constant real-valued continuous function on $X$ is denoted by $C(X)$ and $NC(X)$, respectively.

Clearly, $C(X)\not=\emptyset$ since every constant function on $X$ is continuous. Also, if $|X|=1$, then $NC(X)=\emptyset$.

Does there exists a topological space $X$ with $|X|>1$ and [non-trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385604/prove-that-every-continuous-real-valued-function-on-an-indiscrete-space-is-const), which $NC(X)=\emptyset$. In the other words, does there exists a topological space $X$ with $|X|>1$ such that every real-valued continuou functions on $X$ is constant?

Comment: In General Topology  by Engelking there is given an example of an infinite space which is $T_1$ and $T_3$ and  on which every continuous real-valued function  is constant. I may try to find it in my copy.

Comment: In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1047452/12042) I describe a construction, due to Eric van Douwen, that starts with any $T_3$ space having two points that cannot be separated by a continuous real-valued function and produces a $T_3$ space on which every real-valued continuous function is constant. In the highlighted section of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/386811/12042) I describe a relatively simple example, dut to John Thomas, of a $T_3$ space with two points that cannot be separated by a continuous real-valued function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another non-trivial example:

Let $X$ be an infinite set and $\mathcal T$ the co-finite topology on $X$. Then $C(X)$ consists of only constant functions.

Comment: +1. Note that what's really going on here is: if $X$ is a topological space with no disjoint nonempty open sets, then $X$ has no nonconstant continuous maps to any Hausdorff space. This may seem like a very restrictive condition, but there are natural spaces which have it - in particular, the [Zariski topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology).

Answer (score 5):

Sure, take any space $X$ endowed with the [trivial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology).

**Edit:** There are also nontrivial examples, for example consider $\{\emptyset, A, X\}$ for any arbitrary subset $A \subset X$.

Comment: Thx.  The question is edited.

Comment: I have extended my answer. Please refrain from changing questions too much, as this invalidates previous answers and generates confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You can see [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969089?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Edwin Hewitt, where it is proved that for every cardinal number $\aleph$ which is not the sum of $\aleph_0$ cardinal numbers less than $\aleph$, there exists a Hausdorff space $X$ with $|X|=\aleph$ such that every continuous real function on $X$ is constant.

Some examples by Urysohn and Pospišil are mentioned.

Theorem 2 in the paper by Hewitt exhibits a countable Hausdorff space on which every continuous real function is constant. The construction is due to R. F. Arens.

[image]

1. Edwin Hewitt, *On two problems of Urysohn*, Annals of Mathematics
   Second Series, Vol. 47, No. 3 (Jul., 1946), pp. 503–509
2. Paul Urysohn, *Über die Mächtigkeit der zusammenhängenden Mengen*, Mathematische Annalen, 94 (1925), 262–295
3. Bedřich Pospišil, *Trois notes sur les espaces abstraites*, Spisy vidáváne přirodoveckou Fakultou Masarykovy Univerzity, Čis. 249, 1937